# HTML5 Video in cordova android app has sound but no video

Tags: android, html, cordova, video

I am developing an Android App with cordova and tried to embed a html5 video element to play a local file.
The device is running Android 4.2.2. 
My implementation look like this. The file is located in the res/raw/ folder.

```
<video controls width="1024" height="496">
    <source src="android.resource://com.mypackage/raw/video" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

The problem is that i can hear the sound of the video playing and use the controls but i am not seeing any image. When i open the video in fullscreen it works.

Did someone experience something similar and has a solution?

Thanks

Comment: do you have android:hardwareAccelerated set to true in the manifest? See the comments on https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414

Comment: Yes, i tried it with hardware acceleration disabled and endabled but none of it helped.